# Finding solutions to equations using inequalities

Tags: inequality

Find all positive solutions of the given system of equations:- $$x+y+z=1$$$$x^3+y^3+z^3+xyz=x^4+y^4+z^4+1$$I did the following:-
$x+y+z=1 \therefore xyz \le \frac 1{27} \therefore x^4+y^4+z^4+1\ge 4(\frac {x+y+z}{4})^4+1\ge \frac {65}{64}$. I am not able to find a contradiction to this. Please give a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^p + y^p + z^p$ is a convex function of $p$ for positive $x,y,z$, so 
$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \le \ldots$.

Comment: could you please elaborate??

Comment: $3 = (2/3) 4 + (1/3) 1$ so $f(3) \le (2/3) f(4) + (1/3) f(1)$.

Comment: Is it a general fact that when $f(x)$ is concave, then $p=Aq+Br=>f(p)\le Af(q)+Bf(r)$? Could you give me the proof of this ?

Comment: Also I proved that $f(4)\ge \frac {65}{64}$....so how would it help??

Comment: The general statement is that if $f$ is convex on an interval, $f(t x + (1-t)y) \le t f(x) + (1-t) f(y)$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ and $x$ and $y$ in the interval.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: You already know $xyz \le 1/27$, and $f(1) = x + y + z = 1$, so
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + xyz \le 1/3 + 1/27 + (2/3) (x^4 + y^4 + z^4) < 1 + x^4 + y^4 + z^4$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19871/discussion-between-abhishek-bakshi-and-robert-israel).